# Change Primary Key of .edmx

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I have a .edmx file generated from a database having table "table1".

table1 has following attributes.

```
ID: Int (Primary Key)
Name: String
Tag: String
Description: String
```

In my edmx file, I want to change primary key from ID to (Name, Tag). How can I do that?

Comment: why don't you change that in your database and then run the Update Wizard of your EDMX model?

Comment: I understand your point, but we have a very big solution and it is difficult to change primary key at Database. So as a work around, we are currently updating edmx file.
Solution, to update primary key in edmx, change PropertyRef in SSDL, CSDL and entity mappings to the desired column.

Comment: You may want to have a look at new release of EF, EF6.1 - there mapping api is made public and you have a lot of customization options available. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

In the .edmx file, CSDL section, look for a  tag for the element you want to change:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="DatabaseFirst.BloggingModel" ... >
        <EntityType Name="Blog">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="BlogId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="BlogId" Type="InT32" ...  />
```

Change the Name attribute in the PropertyRef and Property tags to your new desired primary key name.